# CLI program to download album art

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
$ pwd
/home/$USER/music/ripped_music/Monty_Python-Instant_Record_Collection
$ ls
01.The_Executive_Intro.mp3
...
16.The_Lumberjack_Song.mp3
$ mystery_command_or_script .
$ ls
01.The_Executive_Intro.mp3
...
16.The_Lumberjack_Song.mp3
album_cover.jpg
$
```

Somewhere in the guts of Rhythmbox, totem, etc. this is being done.  I'd like to be able to do it myself.

I don't need help actually writing a script.  I'd really just like to know if there's something like CDDB for album covers.  (Scraping albumart.org is the current working solution.)

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do with scripts? Do you want to edit scripts that are used by applications and change their values for different/improved functionality or do you want to write new once for a specific application like Rhythmbox?! Can you please edit your question and add more information!

Comment: Here's a script to get you started: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/post/114627/#p114627

Comment: Okay, I've edited to show an example of what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[glyrc](https://github.com/sahib/glyr/downloads) is the CLI program you're looking for.  Once you've got it compiled and installed, this script will do what you want

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) music_file.mp3"
  exit 1
fi

FILE="$1"

ALBUM="$( id3v2 --list "$FILE" |sed -n 's/TALB[^:]*: *//p' )"
ARTIST="$( id3v2 --list "$FILE" |sed -n 's/TPE1[^:]*: *//p' )"

glyrc cover --artist "$ARTIST" --album "$ALBUM"
```

To compile glyrc following [the author's directions](https://github.com/sahib/glyr/wiki/Compiling) you must first

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libcurl3-dev cmake libglib2.0-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

While trying to do the same I found Coverlovin, https://launchpad.net/coverlovin/+download and it worked OK for me.

Thanks to webupd8 for signalling it.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/recursively-download-cover-art-for-all.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for now.  Unless some "official" way pops up, nathwill's is the answer.

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename $0) music_file.mp3"
  exit 1
fi

FILE="$1"

SEARCHTERM="$( \
/usr/bin/id3v2 --list "$FILE" |sed -n '/^Album *: */ {
  s///
  s/ *Year: *\([^,]*\),.*$/ \1/
  s/  */+/g
  p
}' )"

TOP="http://www.albumart.org/index.php?searchkey="
BOT="&itempage=1&newsearch=1&searchindex=Music"
URL="$TOP""$SEARCHTERM""$BOT"

IMGURL="$(wget -O - "$URL" |grep 'View larger image' |head -1 |sed 's/^.*<a href="\([^"]*\)"  *title="View larger image".*$/\1/')"

wget -O cover.jpg "$IMGURL"
```

Comment: A script that used [glyrc](https://github.com/sahib/glyr/downloads%20glyrc) to fetch album art and [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) to extract an APIC image inside the mp3 would be an official answer.  I'll write one later, but if somebody beats me to the punch, they've answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

`gmusicbrowser` searches Google Images for cover art.

`Rhythmbox`, according to its [FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/Rhythmbox/FAQ/), uses [last.fm](http://www.last.fm) to download cover art.  It used to use [discogs](http://www.discogs.com) (according to a bug report in 2010 I found) but Rhythmbox got banned from it.